# Drag and Drop from Flash/Flex to HTML and Vice-Versa

Tags: html, ajax, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there a library simplifying the process of dragging and dropping between the Flash/Flex environment and the surrounding browser?

I've done some research on the process, and so far the closest thing that I have found is from [HTML to Flash in a Floorplanning application](http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2008/11/06/dragndrop-from-html-to-flash/).  I have yet to find a demo going in the other direction however.

Is there a simpler way to do this now?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't even think it was possible at first until I looked at that link, and I agree with their description that it will be very difficult to get working on all browsers / OS's.